# What framework to use for teaching Front-end development in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gui, user-interface, gui-builder

I teach an undergraduate level computer science in Computer Graphics and User Interfaces. We cover UX, Designing and building UIs, and graphics programming (2D and 3D).

In the past I've done this course in Java, but I would like to switch to Javascript. So my question is what framework should I use for the Building UIs part? Options seem to be React, Angular, and a few others I'm not very familiar with. This will likely be the students' first exposure to Javascript. I have done a tiny bit of React, but my Javascript experience is a bit dated, so my own comfort level isn't really a factor. My requirements are easy to learn and commonly used in the software industry. I plan to use WebGL for the graphics programming section.

Other languages the students learn prior to the course are Python, Java, and C#.

Comment: For teaching purposes? None. They should learn Javascript, not a framework. Start with pure HTML/CSS/JS and add small bits at a time.

Comment: @Alejandro funny you say that as that's how I learned, before there were frameworks like React. There are so many jobs asking for React and Angular that I thought it would help them be more prepared. But I think you are right- stick to the basics.